# In python, why string.count() is faster than loop?

Tags: python, algorithm

In leetcode, I there's a question to check if a disordered series of string "U","D","L","R" will form a circle.

My submission is like:

```
def judgeCircle(moves):

    l=r=u=d=0

    for i in moves:
        if i == 'L':
            l+=1
        if i == 'D':
            d+=1
        if i == 'R':
            r+=1
        if i == 'U':
            u+=1

    return ((l-r)==0) and ((u-d)==0)
```

and the judger think it cost 239ms
while another single line solution:

```
def judgeCircle(moves):
    return (moves.count('R')==moves.count('L')) and 
           (moves.count('U')==moves.count('D'))
```

costs only 39ms?

Though I understand the less code, the better, but I thought the 2nd will loop 4 times, am I misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: You should be right from a complexity-based perspective. But who knows how count is implemented. You probably could speedup your code by using if-else instead of continuing checking, or: by summing into an array which is accessed by asci-code from your chars.

Comment: The `.count` method can do its looping at C speed, which is faster than an explicit Python loop. But you could speed up your Python loop a little by using `elif`, since you don't need to do further tests on a given `i` once you've found a match.

Comment: Loops 4 times at **C speed** (for CPython).

Comment: 1- No conditional branching - 2- builtins are optimized (likely C code under the hood) - 3- Lazy evaluation...

Comment: Also, the 2nd version will skip the `(moves.count('U')==moves.count('D')` part if the first part is false, since `and` short-circuits.

Comment: depending your input string and how much you want to count, `collections.Counter` can be even faster

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, `Counter` can be faster than `.count`, although it can't save time by short-circuiting when the data isn't balanced. See my answer for some stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some `timeit` code showing the speeds of various approaches, using both perfect data with equal counts of all 4 keys, and random data with approximately equal numbers of each key.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Test speeds of various algorithms that check
    if a sequence of U, D, L, R moves make a closed circle.

    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46568696/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2017.10.05
'''

from timeit import Timer
from random import seed, choice, shuffle
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def judge_JH0(moves):
    l = r = u = d = 0
    for i in moves:
        if i == 'L':
            l += 1
        if i == 'D':
            d += 1
        if i == 'R':
            r += 1
        if i == 'U':
            u += 1
    return ((l-r) == 0) and ((u-d) == 0)

def judge_JH1(moves):
    l = r = u = d = 0
    for i in moves:
        if i == 'L':
            l += 1
        elif i == 'D':
            d += 1
        elif i == 'R':
            r += 1
        elif i == 'U':
            u += 1
    return (l == r) and (u == d)

def judge_count(moves):
    return ((moves.count('R') == moves.count('L')) and 
        (moves.count('U') == moves.count('D')))

def judge_counter(moves):
    d = Counter(moves)
    return (d['R'] == d['L']) and (d['U'] == d['D'])

def judge_dict(moves):
    d = {}
    for c in moves:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    return ((d.get('R', 0) == d.get('L', 0)) and 
        (d.get('U', 0) == d.get('D', 0)))

def judge_defdict(moves):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for c in moves:
        d[c] += 1
    return (d['R'] == d['L']) and (d['U'] == d['D'])


# All the functions
funcs = (
    judge_JH0,
    judge_JH1,
    judge_count,
    judge_counter,
    judge_dict,
    judge_defdict,
)

def verify(data):
    print('Verifying...')
    for func in funcs:
        name = func.__name__
        result = func(data)
        print('{:20} : {}'.format(name, result))
    print()

def time_test(data, loops=100):
    timings = []
    for func in funcs:
        t = Timer(lambda: func(data))
        result = sorted(t.repeat(3, loops))
        timings.append((result, func.__name__))
    timings.sort()
    for result, name in timings:
        print('{:20} : {}'.format(name, result))
    print()

# Make some data
keys = 'DLRU'
seed(42)
size = 100

perfect_data = list(keys * size)
shuffle(perfect_data)
print('Perfect')
verify(perfect_data)

random_data = [choice(keys) for _ in range(4 * size)]
print('Random data stats:')
for k in keys:
    print(k, random_data.count(k))
print()
verify(random_data)

loops = 1000
print('Testing perfect_data')
time_test(perfect_data, loops=loops)

print('Testing random_data')
time_test(random_data, loops=loops)
```

**typical output**

```
Perfect
Verifying...
judge_JH0            : True
judge_JH1            : True
judge_count          : True
judge_counter        : True
judge_dict           : True
judge_defdict        : True

Random data stats:
D 89
L 100
R 101
U 110

Verifying...
judge_JH0            : False
judge_JH1            : False
judge_count          : False
judge_counter        : False
judge_dict           : False
judge_defdict        : False

Testing perfect_data
judge_counter        : [0.11746118000155548, 0.11771785900054965, 0.12218693499744404]
judge_count          : [0.12314812499971595, 0.12353860199800692, 0.12495016200409736]
judge_defdict        : [0.20643479600403225, 0.2069275510002626, 0.20834802299941657]
judge_JH1            : [0.25801684000180103, 0.2689959089984768, 0.27642749399819877]
judge_JH0            : [0.36819701099739177, 0.37400564400013536, 0.40291943999909563]
judge_dict           : [0.3991459790049703, 0.4004156189985224, 0.4040740730051766]

Testing random_data
judge_count          : [0.061543637995782774, 0.06157537500257604, 0.06704995800100733]
judge_counter        : [0.11995147699781228, 0.12068584300141083, 0.1207217440023669]
judge_defdict        : [0.2096717179956613, 0.21544414199888706, 0.220649760995002]
judge_JH1            : [0.261116588000732, 0.26281095200101845, 0.2706491360004293]
judge_JH0            : [0.38465088899829425, 0.38476935599464923, 0.3921787180006504]
judge_dict           : [0.40892754300148226, 0.4094729179996648, 0.4135226650032564]
```

These timings were obtained on my old 2GHz 32 bit machine running Python 3.6.0 on Linux.

---

Here are a couple more functions.

```
def judge_defdictlist(moves):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for c in moves:
        d[c].append(c)
    return (len(d['R']) == len(d['L'])) and (len(d['U']) == len(d['D']))

# Sort to groups in alphabetical order: DLRU
def judge_sort(moves):
    counts = [sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(moves))]
    return (counts[0] == counts[3]) and (counts[1] == counts[2])
```

`judge_defdictlist` is slower than `judge_defdict` but faster than `judge_JH1`, and of course it uses more RAM than `judge_defdict`.

`judge_sort` is slower than `judge_JH0`, but faster than `judge_dict`.

Comment: It's really impressive experiment! I learn a lot, thank you very much! So it also means the timing on LeetCode is not very accurate. I should do more experient in future and know better \how it works. Tnx!

Answer (score 4):

Both code samples have algorithmic complexity of `O(n)`, but you shouldn't be fooled by big O as it only shows trend. Execution time for an `O(n)` algorithm can be expressed  as `C * n` where `C` is constant which depends on many factors.

For `.count()` code, you'll need to do 4 loops in `string_count()` C function, but C functions are fast. It also uses some advanced algorithms inside like [fastsearch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L130). Only string search is performed here, minimum interpreter overheads.

In the pure Python code you need only single loop, but each iteration will require to execute much more lower-level code because Python is the interpreted language*. For example, you're creating *new unicode or string* object for each iteration of the loop, and creating objects is a very expensive operation. Since integer objects are immutable, you'll need to re-create them for each counter.

<sup>* Assuming you're using CPython interpreter, which is pretty much default</sup>

Comment: Actually, since those `str` constants are immutable, the interpreter reuses the same objects in CPython. There are many such optimizations

Comment: Thanks, guys! I think I understand better now.